# MongoDB indexes and the $or operator

Tags: mongodb, operator-keyword, indexing

Sorry if this has been asked before. I couldn't find a definitive answer. Can I query on a mongodb index if my query contains the $or operator? My query looks something like this:

```
    // find everything in the collection
    $cursor = $collection->find(array(
   '$or' => array( 
        array('album_id' => array(
            '$in' => $this->my_album_ids
            ),
        'type' => array(
            '$in' => array('like','comment')
            )
         ),
       array(
    'user_id' => (int)session_item('user_id'),
        'type' => 'message',
        'reply' => 'no'
         )
       ),
        'timestamp' => array('$gt' => (int)$since)))->sort(array('timestamp'=>-1))->skip($start)->limit($amount);
```

The Example is in PHP, but I guess this is applicable to any language.

**Update:**

The following are my indexes, but the above query does not use them. It looks right to me though.

```
    $collection->ensureIndex(array(
        'album_id' => 1,
        'type' => 1,
        'timestamp' => -1,
    ));

    $collection->ensureIndex(array(
        'user_id' => 1,
        'type' => 1,
        'reply' => 1,
        'timestamp' => -1,
    ));
```

Here is my explain()

```
Array
(
    [cursor] => BasicCursor
    [nscanned] => 12
    [nscannedObjects] => 12
    [n] => 6
    [scanAndOrder] => 1
    [millis] => 0
    [nYields] => 0
    [nChunkSkips] => 0
    [isMultiKey] => 
    [indexOnly] => 
    [indexBounds] => Array
        (
        )

    [allPlans] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cursor] => BasicCursor
                    [indexBounds] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [oldPlan] => Array
        (
            [cursor] => BasicCursor
            [indexBounds] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, an $or query will use indexes as appropriate. For example :

```
> db.test.ensureIndex({a:1})
> db.test.ensureIndex({b:1})
> db.test.find({$or:[{a:1}, {b:2}]}).explain()
{
        "clauses" : [
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1",
                        "nscanned" : 0,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                        "n" : 0,
                        "millis" : 0,
                        "nYields" : 0,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "a" : [
                                        [
                                                1,
                                                1
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor b_1",
                        "nscanned" : 0,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                        "n" : 0,
                        "millis" : 1,
                        "nYields" : 0,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "b" : [
                                        [
                                                2,
                                                2
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "nscanned" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "n" : 0,
        "millis" : 1
}
```

Comment: Cool, it's good to know it's possible. However my query and index seem to still ignore each other. I've updated my post with how the index is being created. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely one of your inner or clauses does not qualify for the specified indexes. Did you do explain() on the seperate parts and see if that uses the correct index? It's helpful to post questions in shell syntax rather than a specific language. I can't read most of the above without more effort than i'm willing to put in ;)

Comment: If I were you, I would work through each part of your query by building it up slowly, without the OR clause. Prove to your self that the order in your compound indexes is correct. Then continue to build up to the final query you need. I am sure your problem will quickly be resolved.

Comment: `db.collection.ensureIndex` has been [removed in v5.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) and renamed `createIndex`

Answer (score 4):

Mongo use no IndexBounds on an sorted OR Query.
Try

```
db.test.find({$or:[{a:1}, {b:2}]}).sort(somesort).explain();
```

and IndexBounds use with `$minElement` and `$maxElement`