# index is not being used

Tags: mongodb, indexing

So I have this index

```
 db.contact.ensureIndex(
 {
   'first_name':1,
   'last_name':1,
   'company_name':1,
   'title':1,
   'email':1,
   'phone_number':1,
   'state':1,
   'list_id':1
});
```

if I run this query with an `$or` the index is not being used

```
 db.contact.find(
                {
                  $or: [
                          {'first_name':/sales/i},
                          {'last_name':/sales/i},
                          {'company_name':/sales/i},
                          {'title':/sales/i},
                          {'email':/sales/i},
                          {'phone_number':/sales/i},
                          {'state':/sales/i}
                  ] 
                }).explain();
```

output:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor", //Btree Index not being used !?
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 0,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "server" : "",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: Creating an index for each item seems to be the solution as per: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6875645/2805783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given following docs:

```
(1){first_name: 'sales', last_name: 'something', company_name: 'something'},
(2){first_name: 'something', last_name: 'sales', company_name: 'something'},
(3){first_name: 'something', last_name: 'something', company_name: 'sales'}
```

you would like to get all of them in your result
So if mongodb were using {first_name: 1, last_name: 1, company_name: 1}) index, it would exclude automatically record number two and three since first_name in these two cases is different. So in order to get the remaining documents you would have to scan all the documents anyways.

PS

It seems that you are runnig you query against empty collection ?