# How to search through multiple documents having object as field value for a keyword using index "text" in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search

I want to search if a keyword present in any of the fields in documents. some field values are objects.so it is also needed to check whether the keyword present inside that object also.
so I came across the following solution.
**collections:** *products(having companyId as foreign key), company*

**mongoQuery**
`db.products.aggregate([{$match:{$text:{$search:"hello"}}},{$lookup:{from:"companies",localField:"companyId",foreignField:"_id",as:"company"}},{$unwind:"$company"}])`

**result**
`

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("63832de4e9dbcd9b2942ded7"),
    companyId: [ ObjectId("6383048ae9dbcd9b2942dece") ],
   title: 'hello world',
    imageUrl: 'https://drive.google.com/file/image',
    company: {
      _id: ObjectId("6383048ae9dbcd9b2942dece"),
      name: 'name1',
      url: 'name1.com'
    }
  }
]
```

`

But problem is that i have another document where 'company.name' having value "hello".By using above query it doesn't return the second document.How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**$or** is your correct approach: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Just use it with **.find** as example links shows and you will get an array of documents.

Comment: I want to return the document if the keyword is present in any of the fields even if the keyword may be part of a value. for example index searching, but problem is that index searching in the atlas doesn't work with $lookup for version 5.0

Comment: With $or you are able to match a part of the value in each of the properties. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872724/mongodb-indexes-and-the-or-operator here you are an example with $or and indexes. I hope it would be helpful